# General Comparisons vs Value Comparisons

Tags: xquery

Why does XQuery treat the following expressions differently?

- `() = 2`  returns `false` (general Comparison)
- `() eq 2` returns an empty sequence  (value Comparison)

Comment: Please only ask one question per question, if they've got different topics. I removed your second question for now, please ask it again. You can still get the contents in the edit log. Also, there are no `// comments` in XQuery, use `(: comment :)` instead.

Comment: Nice question by the way, I was puzzled until I looked up in the specs. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This effect is explained in the XQuery specifications. For XQuery 3, it is in chapter [3.7.1, **Value Comparisons**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-value-comparisons) (highlighting added by me):

> 1. **Atomization is applied to the operand.** The result of this operation is called the atomized operand.
> 2. **If the atomized operand is an empty sequence, the result of the value comparison is an empty sequence**, and the implementation need not evaluate the other operand or apply the operator. However, an implementation may choose to evaluate the other operand in order to determine whether it raises an error.

Thus, if you're comparing two single element sequences (or scalar values, which are equal to those), you will as expected receive a `true`/`false` value:

- `1 eq 2` is  `false`
- `2 eq 2` is  `true`
- `(1) eq 2` is `false`
- `(2) eq 2` is  `true`
- `(2) eq (2)` is  `true`
- and so on

But, if one or both of the operands is the empty list, you will receive the empty list instead:

- `() eq 2` is `()`
- `2 eq ()` is `()`
- `() eq ()` is `()`

This behavior allows you to pass-through empty sequences, which could be used as a kind of `null` value here. As @adamretter added in the comments, the empty sequence `()` has the effective boolean value of `false`, so even if you run something like `if ( () eq 2) ...`, you won't observe anything surprising.

If any of the operands contains a list of more than one element, it is a type error.

**General comparison**, `$sequence1 = $sequence2` tests if *any* element in `$sequence1` has an equal element in `$sequence2`. As this semantically already supports sequences of arbitrary length, no atomization must be applied.

#### Why?

The difference comes from the requirements imposed by the operators' signatures. If you compare sequences of arbitrary length in a set-based manner, there is no reason to include any special cases for empty sequences -- if an empty sequence is included, the comparison is automatically `false` by definition.

For the operators comparing *single values*, one has to consider the case where an empty sequence is passed; the decision was to not raise an error, but also return a value equal to `false`: the empty sequence. This allows to use the empty sequence as a kind of `null` value, when the value is unknown; anything compared to an unknown value can never be `true`, but must not (necessarily) be false. If you need to, you could check for an `empty(...)` result, if so, one of the values to be compared was unknown; otherwise they're simply different. In Java and other languages, a `null` value would have been used to achieve similar results, in Haskell there's the [`Data.Maybe`](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Maybe).

Comment: Perhaps it is also worth mentioning that the *effective boolean value* of `()` is false(). So when you do `if(() eq 2)` the test will always result in false().

Comment: I know what mean general comparisons and value comparisons. I would like know why the behavior that you have described for value comparisons (like Atomization ...etc.) is not applied to general comparisons, or the inverse!

Comment: I somewhat already implied that in my answer. I extended the answer wrapping it up in a few words. In the end, its a matter of _definition of the language_; I wrote what I think are the reasons for doing so.